# Continuous complex series

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following question:

Let $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^{n!}
}{n!}$.

Show that $f$ is  continuous on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ (the closed unit disc).

Answer (score 3):

[Weierstrass' $M$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) gives uniform convergence of the series on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, and the terms are continuous, so $f$ is too.

Comment: I have an other question: how to prove that $f$ has no analytic continuation through $\partial\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: For non-continuation, I think the easiest is to look at the behavior of $f'$ as you approach the boundary.

Comment: Is it true to say that if $f'$ has no  analytic continuation through $\partial\mathbb{D}$ then $f$ has no  analytic continuation through $\partial\mathbb{D}$? And how to prove that?

Comment: If there was an analytic continuation to some larger disk, the Taylor expansion of $f$ would have radius of convergence larger thatn $1$.

Comment: Take a look at the Hadamard gap theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%E2%80%93Hadamard_gap_theorem which is probably what inspired this problem.